# Nothing appears on the Panel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, indicator, notification-area

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. This was my first Ubuntu installation. The Unity Launcher and Panel did not appear at first but I fixed it by searching from the internet. Now the Panel appears, but it's empty. Only the title of the active window appears and nothing else. The power button, the clock, mail, sound, other indicators nothing appears.

I tried resetting and reinstalling unity. I tried `killall unity-panel-services` but it says `no process found`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity

unity --reset-icons
```

**Edit:** Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/76951#76951) helping you?

Comment: This did not work too.

Comment: Editted the post, maybe is that helping.

Comment: No. last command makes the launcher,the menu bar on the top of screen and the top bar of the windows disappear. I have to use setsid unity to get them back again.

Answer (score 0):

open startup application and add this command

> **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service**

[image]

after logout and login again to your account

Comment: It makes no difference. I have a 64 bit laptop, does that make any difference?